# Json tranformers: missing implicit for reduce

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

Following Play's docs at http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.2/ScalaJsonTransformers:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

val gizmo2gremlin = (
    (__ \ 'name).json.put(JsString("gremlin")) and
    (__ \ 'description).json.pickBranch(
            (__ \ 'size).json.update( of[JsNumber].map{ case JsNumber(size) => JsNumber(size * 3) } ) and
            (__ \ 'features).json.put( Json.arr("skinny", "ugly", "evil") ) and
            (__ \ 'danger).json.put(JsString("always")) 
            reduce
    ) and
    (__ \ 'hates).json.copyFrom( (__ \ 'loves).json.pick )
) reduce
```

I assume `of[JsNumber]` above actually should have been `Format.of[JsNumber]`, but even after that, the code will not compile:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter reducer: play.api.libs.functional.Reducer[play.api.libs.json.JsObject,B]
               reduce
               ^
```

Am I missing an import, or is there an error in the docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the missing import is:

```
import play.api.libs.json.Reads._
```